# Getting more information about 'object Object'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

The two console.logs in the code below show the following. The data objects are in json format with 'title', 'position' and 'content'. However, I'm not sure how to view data in a console.log. For example, I tried `console.log("data " + data[0].title)` to get the title of the first data object, but it returned undefined.  As for the 'this' object, I don't actually know what it is. This is the initialize function in a router view of a backbone app, which I'm trying to deconstruct but I can't figure out what 'this' is in this context.

```
**this** [object Object]



**data** [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

**code**

```
 initialize: function (options)
        {

            var _this = this;
            console.log("this " + this);
            $.ajax({
                url: "json/Backboneapp_data.json",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {},
                async: false,
                success: function (data)
                {
                    console.log("data " + data)
                    _this._data = data;
                    _this._items = new ItemCollection(data);
                    _this._view = new MenuView({ model: _this._items });
                    _this._view.render();
                    Backbone.history.loadUrl();
                }

            });

            return this;
        },
```

Comment: Instead of `console.log` try put word `debugger` and if developer tool are open you will get all the possible information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add to a string, the object gets cast to a string. If you console.log just the object, many environments (eg web kit inspector) will let you inspect the object within the console.

```
console.log(this)
```